# Can I Host Multiple Websites on Different Domains within A Single Google Apps for Business Account?

Tags: google-workspace, google-classic-sites, domain

I have 2 domains: example1.com and example2.com

Example1.com is all setup, have a simple website, email users, shared calendar, etc.

I need to put up a 1-page site under domain example2.com.

I upgraded to Google Apps for Business, which enables me to add another Domain, under Domain Settings.

I created a new website, but when I went to map the second site to example2.com domain, I only get the option to put in a sub-domain name, for example: [***_*__**].example1.com

Since Google Apps for Business gives me the ability to add *multiple domains* to my account, can't I point example2.com at the second site?

Or, is adding a domain, simply for gmail purposes only?

Comment: I have the same exact question amd can not find an answer. Maybe I will create an additional gmail account to make the website and forward mail to the first to consolidate email.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I apologize for answering my own question, but short of no info, this will have to do.

It appears that the only benefit and/or settings I can find on Google Apps for Business in regard to Domains is as follows:

- Domain Settings/Domain Names: Add a domain
- Gmail: Seems the only thing one can do with an additional Domain is manage Domain-specific Gmail accounts.